# Should questions needing no clear answers be allowed?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28406/a-monster-who-is-also-a-savior) kinda shocked me with its last paragraph:

> Do not post the solution directly. Not even in as spoiler. Just write 3 more unique properties of the person/thing you think it is so that the interest isn't lost. After the correct answer is picked, then you can post the one (or few) words answer directly.

What I understand from this site is that you should answer puzzles with the answer to the question and clues into spoilers so the answer can only be viewed by those who want to. By saying you only get a shot at the question without disclosing what you think the answer to the riddle is is not in the spirit of riddles here.

So my question is that are questions forcing users to post an answer ***without the actual solution (or attempt)*** allowed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that's not allowed. This is a Q&A site, and we try to be a good repository of both high-quality questions and high-quality answers. Answers should fully answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I see. I should edit my question then.

It happens in terms of puzzles that when one solid, concrete answer is given, it tends to act as a seed crystal and starts impacting other people's opinion. The idea was that once you form your opinion about the answer, you post 3 properties of that person/thing. For example, the person answering that question stated "moon" as the answer. This is a solid, clear answer by that person. The request was to not post "moon" directly, but post 3 properties of moon which clearly imply it is moon.

Once the right answer is announced, then the one word answer can be presented directly in all answers. Well, at least that was my idea.

Btw there IS a solid, direct answer to that puzzle. I'd still edit the last part to remove the no direct answer.

Comment: That is why we have spoilers... to allow the answer to only be shown to those who want to

Comment: I have other thoughts about the matter, but I will respect the community's perspective.